# How to measure quantity difference between a nonlinear system of equations and its linearization?

Tags: electromagnetism, non-linear-systems, linearized-theory

I faced such a problem. I have a nonlinear system for control synthesis and I should compare not only my controllers but also a linear version of my system to describe the legitimacy of this linearization. But it never occurred to me how to compare it in numerical. We often do it in a frequency domain for linear systems comparing bandwidth, gain, or phase margin. And we have a numerical result. But I can't do the Laplace transform (for example) because of no superposition principle being. I heard about nonlinear Fourier transform but I doubt that it could help me.

Comment: Is it possible to Taylor expand it around the linearization point (the operating parameters)? I think they did that in one of the labs I went to. There might be better ways of course, maybe Lyapunov function?

Comment: I did Taylor approximation and have a linear model. But I need to prove the legitimacy of it. The Lyapunov function also doesn't fetch the numerical features in order to compare the former and the latter systems of equations.

Comment: There might be methods specific to the type of system you're concerned with, but if you could calculate the next term in the Taylor expansion, it could give you an idea of the size of your error.

Comment: It sounds good. But I would like to know what I've lost after linearization and using linear regulator for this system. I couldn't examine this second-order term in Teilor's series using linear methods from the control theory

Comment: Are you able to run the full system? Maybe you could compare the theoretical output from linear version to the actual output somehow, to estimate the error...?

Comment: I could do it and try to, but the result depends on the simulation time. The mo time I choose, the more error is. And I started to look up another method. I can't get Fourier transformation. I hear about comparing through norms of the difference of functions.